# Will a thick layer of coffee grounds cause girdling?

Tags: growth

If you put a thick layer of coffee grounds on top of a plant, like a tomato, or a blueberry bush, will girdling occur?

If so how do you easily fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Girdling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girdling) is the removal of a ring of bark around the circumference of a tree. This usually kills the tree and is often seen due to lawn mower or whipper snipper work.

Mulching with any organic matter will not cause girdling but could cause other problems. Depending on soil types, mulch, weather that season and plant types too much mulch could encourage fungal growth in the mulch and plant.

If you have mulch close to the stem of any plant or tree just rake it back and leave a clear perimeter of soil of at least one inch around the plant.